# Can't display vector layer using L.vectorGrid.protobuf

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, vector-grid, pbf

I use [mapbox/tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe)  to create .pbf tiles.
But when I try to display them using [L.vectorGrid.protobuf](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) nothing is rendered, although I see that proper .pbf files are requested and downloaded by browser.

I suspect that missing options parameter is the root of the problem but I am not sure:

```
var layer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf('http://my_static_files_server/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf')
map.addLayer(layer)
```

Is it necessary to set options if I want just display vector layer represented by single polygon?

How can I set common options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the similar problem reported at https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/issues/582
By default `tippecanoe` creates gzip-compressed tiles, but L.vectorGrid.protobuf relies on uncompressed.
Running `tippecanoe` with `--no-tile-compression` option solved the problem.